# Ruby & Rspec, effectively testing an array of values?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have a model with a number of similar values that I'm looking to test, and I'm struggling to find the most efficient way to do so.

I have a model `Workweek`, that has a float field for each day of the week (`"#{weekday}_hours"`), which allows an employee to enter their daily hours for that day. I want to test and make sure that no value higher than 24 can be entered for a given day.

While I could just write 7 different tests for each day of the week, I'd like to do somehting like this:

```
let(:workweek) { create_week }
 [
  'monday',
  'tuesday',
  'wednesday',
  'thursday',
  'friday',
  'saturday',
  'sunday'
 ].each do |day|
  it "shoud not allow #{day}_hours to exceed 24" do
    # Test body here
  end
```

But I'm struggling with the attribute assignment. I'd like to something like `workweek.#{day}_hours`, but This obviously won't work as 'm not in a string.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do then

```
workweek.public_send "#{day}_hours"
```

[`#public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Object.html#method-i-public_send) method accept method names as `Symbol` or `String` instances.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I ended up with `workweek.public_send("#{day}_hours=", 25)`